# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock hidden controls at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I need your help. I would like to understand why when running ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock the controls of my page disappear and reappear only after confirmation of Ok?

```
Protected Sub ddlDeckFittingCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlDeckFittingCategory.SelectedIndexChanged

    If txbNumberofColumns.Text = "" Or Me.txbShellDiameter.Text = "" Then

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Page.GetType, "alert", "alert('Informe o valor do Diâmetro do Casco (m)!');", True)
        ddlDeckFittingCategory.SelectedValue = -1
    Else


        If Request("TipoTela") = 1 Then


            If ddlDeckFittingCategory.SelectedValue = "Typical" Then
                objFinttings_temp.IncluirFittingsTempTQIFLTTipico(Session("cod_usuario_usu"))
                'objFinttings_temp.AtualizaFittingsTempColumnWell_24_in_Diam(CType(txbNumberofColumns.Text, Double))
                objFinttings_temp.AtualizaFittingsTempColumnWell_24_in_Diam(txbNumberofColumns.Text)
                tbFittingsFonte.Visible = True
                tbFittingsFonte.HeaderText = ""
                TcPrincipal.ActiveTabIndex = 6

                Dim dvConsultarCodFonteEmFittingsTempPorUsuario As DataView = objFinttings_temp.ConsultarCodFonteEmFittingsTempPorUsuario(Session("cod_usuario_usu"))
                Session("cod_fonte_fon") = dvConsultarCodFonteEmFittingsTempPorUsuario.Table.Rows(0)("cod_fonte_fon")
                Session("ddlDeckFittingCategory") = ddlDeckFittingCategory.SelectedValue
            Else
                objFinttings_temp.IncluirFittingsTQIFLTDetalhado(0)
                tbFittings.Visible = True
                tbFittings.HeaderText = ""
                TcPrincipal.ActiveTabIndex = 6

            End If
            GrvFittingsFonte.DataBind()

        Else



            If ddlDeckFittingCategory.SelectedValue = "Typical" Then
                objFinttings_temp.IncluirFittingsTempTQIFLTTipico(Session("cod_usuario_usu"))
                'objFinttings_temp.AtualizaFittingsTempColumnWell_24_in_Diam(CType(txbNumberofColumns.Text, Double))
                objFinttings_temp.AtualizaFittingsTempColumnWell_24_in_Diam(txbNumberofColumns.Text)
                tbFittingsFonte.Visible = True
                tbFittingsFonte.HeaderText = ""
                TcPrincipal.ActiveTabIndex = 6

            Else
                objFinttings_temp.IncluirFittingsTQIFLTDetalhado(Session("cod_fonte_fon"))
                tbFittings.Visible = True
                tbFittings.HeaderText = ""
                TcPrincipal.ActiveTabIndex = 6

            End If
            GrvFittingsFonte.DataBind()

            If ddlSelfSupportingRoof.SelectedValue = 1 Or ddlSelfSupportingRoof.SelectedValue = "-1" Then
                txbNumberofColumns.Enabled = False
                rvNumColuna.Visible = False
                ddlEffectiveColumnDiameter.Enabled = False
                rvDiametroEfetivoColuna.Visible = False
            Else
                txbNumberofColumns.Enabled = True
                rvNumColuna.Visible = True
                ddlEffectiveColumnDiameter.Enabled = True
                rvDiametroEfetivoColuna.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
enter code here
```

Comment: `RegisterClientScriptBlock` runs before the controls are rendered in the browser. Normally you just add script-blocks/functions there that must be used when the controls are loaded. So you could use `RegisterStartupScript` which is triggered when the document was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

use  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()

it will run after the page loads.